# In Javascript, is there a way to convert an object array to parameters on a function call?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have an array such as:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

And I have a function:

```
function f (x, y, z) { ... }
```

I want to call the function with the given array, where each array index is a parameter being passed into the function.  I could do this:

```
f(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

But let's suppose I don't know the length of the array until runtime.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the 'apply' javascript method:

```
f.apply(context, arr);
```

...where `context` will become the value of `this` within the call.

Some info here: http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/apply.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Function` object's `apply` method:

```
var args = [1,2,3];

f.apply(null, args)
```

`apply` takes two arguments, the first being the value of `this` within the function at invocation time, and the second being an array of arguments to pass to the function.